# How to enter Razor within Javascript without quotes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm serializing my model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Model = '@Model.ToJson()';

</script>
```

the ToJson is an extension method:

```
public static string ToJson(this object obj)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var val = serializer.Serialize(obj);
    return val;
}
```

Now I want to access my model in other javascript files by doing:

```
var hello = Model.id;
```

The problem is that it doesn't serialize correctly when I use `'@Model.ToJson()'` because of the quotes.

The serialized object looks like this:

```
var Model = "{ "id": "2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301" }";
```

But in order for me to access id by Model.id it should look like this:

```
var Model = { "id": "2231f87c-a62c-4c2c-8f5d-b76d11942301" };
```

How can I enter razor syntax without quotes? Using asp.net syntax I think it's:

```
var Model = <%=Model.ToJson() %>
```

How do I do the same with razor? Thanks!

Comment: you surround `@Model.ToJson()` call with quotes... Note that you have mismatch between your sample (`'@Model.ToJson()'` and "object looks like" statement `var Model = "{ "id": ` - notice different quote), so you may be running some other code at all...

Answer (score 1):

If you use [this JSON plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) you can do it all on the client and simply things.  If you push up a JSON string, in javascript you could then do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Model = JSON.parse("@Model.JsonString");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Razor by default escapes out the quotes, you need to use [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
var Model = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
```

It will turn that into:

```
var Model = {"id":"whatever"};
```

which is valid javascript.